# Don't display “Next privilege” in the case of suspended users

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, privileges, account-suspension

If you take a look at the reputation tab of an user whose account was suspended, you will see that that user's next privilege will be to be able to participate in meta, which will happen when the reputation of that user becomes 5 or greater. This would be natural in the case of an ordinary user whose reputation happened to be below 5, but it is *not* natural at all in the case of users whose accounts were suspended.

I suggest that, in the case of suspended accounts, no mention is made to the next privilege.

Answer (score 3):

On the contrary, I think it's reasonable to show "Next privilege: participate in meta" because it's a fact that they really can't participate in meta (and do all other actions)

This might be useful *as a reminder for anyone else* to not discuss the user's suspension on the meta because the user won't be able to defend themselves. (the usual "Moderators won't discuss user's suspension publicly unless the user allow/want to")

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be better to show these blocks depending on the state of the profile before suspension.

For example, check [this user page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense?tab=topactivity):

> [image]

It looks kind of strange in multiple ways.

Comment: The not awarded Curious badge is by-design. If you click on it you will see that the criterion “positive question record” has not been fulfilled.